# How can I recognize Image inside Image?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, ocr, image-recognition

So, based on various open source OCR library in Python I can able to detect the text, but now I want to detect that there is a Image also in the image. Example.
 [Text Recognization in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPWgd.png)

But How should I recognize that left bottom image inside this same page?